# Collect data into object according to its term

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this invoice data :

[image: inv]

I have collecting the total tax value per item price and store it on the object with the tax term name key as you see on my console result. Now i want to collection the item serial number of applied tax term, for example `vat@5` applied on 1 to 4 and `tax@22.75` applied on only 5. If i use another object to store the applied s.no. then it is hard to display according to its term. Is there any way to push the data on the same object according to its tax term?

```
var taxz = {};
var keyz = {};

for( var i = 0; i < Price.length; i++ ){
    if( isNaN( Price[i] ) ){ $('td:eq(5)', TR[i+1]).html(""); }
    else { $('td:eq(5)', TR[i+1]).html(Price[i]); }

    if( ! isNaN(Price[i]) ) {

        var Tax_Name = $(Tax_TR[i]).find(":selected").text();
        var Tax_Val = ((Tax_TR[i].value) / 100 * Price[i]).toFixed(2);

        if( Tax_Name in taxz ) {
            //console.log('find');
            taxz[Tax_Name] = tax_sum(taxz, Tax_Name) + parseFloat(Tax_Val);

        }
        else {
            //console.log('not_find');
            taxz[Tax_Name] = tax_sum(taxz, Tax_Name) + parseFloat(Tax_Val);

        }
    }
}

console.log(taxz);


Object { "VAT@5"=158.5, "TAX@22.75"=56.88}
```

Comment: Whoa! Whoa! Whoa! This code is hardly readable. If you write code like this, it'll bring you trouble. Trouble like this. Avoid nested if-else statements, as well as cryptic identifiers and follow the SRP and DRY principle as much as you can. Also, one should carefully format his/her code. `if (taxname in taxz)`: you are doing the exact same thing on each branch. What's the point of the conditional? Also, I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: @Powerslave I am sorry if you can't understand but now its working and thanks to point out principles. I have also added the answer of my own question as well and i am sure after checking the answer's console result you get my point.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. If you don't mind, I'd add an example: in your solution, you violate the DRY principle. There's only a single line that's different across conditional branches. Why not put only that into a conditional scope? Like `if (!(Tax_Name in taxz))` then `taxz[Tax_Name + '_1'] = []` and do everything else in the "common" scope. There are several other things to note besides that but I really won't go into that too deep now.

Answer (score 0):

Its working and i added the following to my code:

```
if( Tax_Name in taxz ) {
    //console.log('find');
    taxz[Tax_Name] = tax_sum(taxz, Tax_Name) + parseFloat(Tax_Val);
    taxz[Tax_Name+'_1'].push(i+1);
}
else {
    //console.log('not_find');
    taxz[Tax_Name] = tax_sum(taxz, Tax_Name) + parseFloat(Tax_Val);
    taxz[Tax_Name+'_1'] = [];
    taxz[Tax_Name+'_1'].push(i+1);
}
```

Now result is:

```
Object { VAT@5=158.5, VAT@5_1=[1, 2, 3, 4], TAX@22.75=56.88, TAX@22.75_1=[5]}
```

This is what i want.